# What is this snippet from Frege's Begriffsschrift saying?

Tags: logic, frege, history-of-logic

I have no background knowledge in logic so I am a little lost about where to begin.

This is the photo I am trying to learn about and it is from Frege’s Begriffsschrift.

[image: This is the photo I am trying to learn about and it is from Frege’s Begriffsschrift.]

Comment: Some clues here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begriffsschrift#Notation_and_the_system

Comment: If you know which proposition this is from Mendelsohn has them rewritten in [*Begriffsschrift* in Modern Notation](http://comet.lehman.cuny.edu/mendel/papers/Adobe%20Versions/AdobeNewBGForms.pdf). See also [On Frege’s *Begriffsschrift* notation for propositional logic by Schlimm](https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~dirk/schlimm2017-begriffsschrift-prefinal.pdf) if you *really* want to learn it. But not even Frege himself used this notation afterwards.

Comment: Great! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The formula is used into the third part of [Begriffsschrift (1879)](https://books.google.it/books?id=v4tBTBlU05sC&pg=PA55), regarding the *General theory of sequences*, not translated in modern symbols by Mendelsohn.

You have to look at: G.Landini, [Frege’s Notations: What They Are and How They Mean (2012)](https://books.google.it/books?id=NUBdAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA62).

The basic component of the complex formula is the "gamma-on-beta of f(x,y)" symbol.

It is defined in §27 (formula 76): it is used to symbolize the *ancestral relation* for objects and reads:

> "x follows y in the f-sequence".

The snippet depicts the substitution used in the derivation of Th.(132): the last but one theorem.

Formula (132) is derived from previous formula (131) using the propositional law (9) [see Mendelshon's translation in modern symbols]:

> **(c ⊃ b) ⊃ ((b ⊃ a) ⊃ (c ⊃ a))**.

The "complex" formulas on the right of the snippet must be substituted in place of **a,c,b** respectively and (132) follows from (131) by detachment.

A very useful brief explanation of this part of Frege's work with the "modern reconstruction" of the proof of (132) and (133) is: George Boolos, [Reading the Begriffsschrift (Mind, 1985)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2254808).